# Rcpp CharacterVector::create number of paramters too small

Tags: r, rcpp

Can anyone suggest me how I can create CharacterVector (I want to name the columns in matrix) with length 30. Seems that function accepts no more than 20 args. The only thing that I thought was to create two vectors and combine them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been discussed before:

- create one with length 15,
- create a second one with length 15 and
- combine the two to create a vector of length 30.

We need a templated creator for each possible length, so there is some cost on our code side.  You could, if you really wanted, locally patch to create one with size 30 -- but I argue that this is not generally needed.

Comment: Or creating a `vector<string>` and converting that to a `CharacterVector` should be fine as well.